# Python - Check List Data to Store Files in Folder Structure

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, directory

I have 16 GoPro cameras filming simultaneously and am writing a Python application to copy and order the video files from the SD cards into a folder structure like this:

project
---- take1
-------- cam1-file1.mp4
-------- cam2-file1.mp4
---- take2
-------- cam1-file2.mp4
-------- cam2-file2.mp4

The cams are started nearly simultaneously using a remote. Therefore, if the **duration** of the videos is within a second of each other, this indicates a "take".

I already got all the metadata like `duration` in miliseconds, the `file_name`, and the `camera_number`as variables, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to get to my final goal of storing these files in correct folders.

I got the following script:

```
for x in range(0, len(meta_array)):

    camera_number = meta_array[x][0]    # String between "01" and "16"
    file_name = meta_array[x][1]        # Filename
    duration = meta_array[x][2]         # Video length in milliseconds

    takes.append([cam,[file_name,duration_ms]])

print(takes)
```

Which outputs:

```
[['01', ['H01-C01-NA-GOPR0150', '78840']], ['01', ['H01-C01-NA-GOPR0151', '37940']], ['02', ['H01-C02-NA-GOPR0238', '78840']], ['02', ['H01-C02-NA-GOPR0239', '37940']]]
```

But I guess I need something more like this:

```
[['01', ['H01-C01-NA-GOPR0150', '78840'], ['H01-C01-NA-GOPR0151', '37940']], ['02', ['H01-C02-NA-GOPR0238', '78840'], ['H01-C02-NA-GOPR0239', '37940']]]
```

And then loop through the whole thing and say "*if duration of cam1, file1 is within 1 second of duration of cam2, file1, place them in folder take1*"

I would greatly appreciate any assistance, because I'm kinda lost in the loops and datatypes.

Comment: what about if files don't fall within the criteria? You don't save them at all?

Comment: @Anzel Thanks! That's indeed a good point. The idea is that if for a certain take there are only 15 files found while there were 16 cameras, then these files are placed in an "incomplete" folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll be happier with a `dict` than with a `list` as `takes`...:

```
import collections
takes = collections.defaultdict(list)

for x in range(0, len(meta_array)):
    camera_number = meta_array[x][0]    # String between "01" and "16"
    file_name = meta_array[x][1]        # Filename
    duration_ms = meta_array[x][2]      # Video length in milliseconds

    takes[camera_number].append([file_name, int(duration_ms)])
```

Given this, you can then continue:

```
all_files = [ [t[0] for t in v] for v in takes.values() ]
all_durations = [ [t[1] for t in v] for v in takes.values() ]
num_attempts = min(len(d) for d in all_durations)

successes = 0

for attempt in range(num_attempts):
    # get lengths for all cameras
    durations = [d[attempt] for d in all_durations]
    discrepancy = max(durations) - min(durations)
    if discrepancy > 1000: continue
    successes += 1
    dest_dir = 'take{}'.format(successes)
    for filename in [f[attempt] for f in all_files]:
        shutil.copy(filename, dest_dir)
```

This has assumptions about where the files are found and where they go, doesn't let you know about takes that failed for too much discrepancy, and so forth.  But it should be adaptable to your exact requirements.

Edited: improved the logic to ensure the proper number of attempts are checked.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! `takes[camera_number].append([file_name,duration_ms])` works better indeed. I do get the following error:

`discrepancy = max(durations) - min(durations) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`

And yes, I should be able to build in error handling and extra checks myself once the basic loop structure is clear.

Comment: @kregus, if the duration field is a string, then just make it an `int`, no?  `takes[camera_number].append([file_name,intduration_ms)])` in other words.  I'm editing the answer to make this obvious fact explicit.

Comment: apologies for causing any confusion, the duration was indeed ms as a string. I changed the copy funtion to `shutil.copy(project_folder.get()+"\\"+filename+".MP4", project_folder.get()+"\\"+dest_dir+"\\"+filename+".MP4")`, which works. However, it creates thousands of takes, while only 2 exist (4 video files, 2 cams, 2 takes per cam). Sorry to bother you again, but would you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @kregus, I had omitted incrementing `attempt`, editing to fix.

Comment: You are an absolute hero, Alex! Thanks so much for this, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Instead of `shutil.copy()` I decided to go with `if not os.path.isdir(project_folder.get()+"\\"+dest_dir):
                    os.mkdir(project_folder.get()+"\\"+dest_dir)

                shutil.move(project_folder.get()+"\\"+filename+".MP4", project_folder.get()+"\\"+dest_dir+"\\"+filename+".MP4")`